# Google Analytics filters. Subsetting results to specific URLs with no parameters or question marks

Tags: url, parameters, filtering, google-analytics-filters

I seem to not being lucky searching for an understandable anwer in this forum, so I decided to make my own question. I apoplogyze for any existing post that I could have missed.

Briefly, I want to know statistics from certain pages that I can address by setting a filter accounting the URL. The problem is that I can also found some visits that were made while administering the site (joomla) which show some queries. 
I would like to get results from pages under, let's say, /index.php/certain_group/ 
(e.g.

- /index.php/certain_group/this-page,
- /index.php/certain/group/another-page)*

but not those like

- /index.php/certain/group/another-page?view=form&layout=edit&a_id=89&return=aHR0cCUzQSUyR...bla bla

I have tried lost of combinations in http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester

I am being able to find only thos that I do not want, I mean, if I use "/index.php/group/.*\?.*$"
I get

- /index.php/certain/group/another-page?view=form&layout=edit&a_id=89&return=aHR0cCUzQSUyR...bla bla

Any clue?
Thanks in advance